# how to put several objects in one template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

How do I pass the object from ClassDetail to CreateNewStudent in order to use it in its template ?

Thanks.

```
class ClassDetail(DetailView):
        context_object_name = "Class"
        template_name = "temp/students.html"
        model = Class

class CreateNewStudent(CreateView):
    model = Student
    form_class = forms.StudentForm
    template_name = "temp/newstudent.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you have two models `Class` and `Student`. In this case better way to create custom view:

```
def myCustomView(request, pk):
  get_class = get_object_or_404(Class, pk=pk)
  student_form = StudentForm
    if request.POST:
      student_form = StudentForm(request.POST)
      if student_form.is_valid():
        ...
        return ...
      else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'get_class':get_class, 'student_form':sudent_form})
    else:
      return render(request, 'index.html', {'get_class':get_class, 'student_form':sudent_form})
```

Comment: I do need to use CBVs, is there any other way to do this with CBVs ?

Comment: According to official documentation "A view that displays a form for creating an object, redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and saving the object.". So, no